# Why is the pre DOM not getting appended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is a code snippet which creates a wrapper `div` then appends a `pre` element inside that. However this does not seem to work.

```
var t = $('#t');
var container = $('<div>');
container.css('position', 'relative');
t.wrap(container);
var pre = $('<pre>');
pre.appendTo(container); // Seems to have no effect
```

When I run this code and inspect the elements I see no `pre` element.

[image: No pre present]

The working demo can be seen here - http://jsfiddle.net/ueb2pq6o/

Comment: *"The full code can be seen here..."* The **full** code should also be in the question. *(Not my dv)*

Comment: I'm not getting the downvotes on this question at all. `wrap` is weird, it's not surprising to find someone misunderstanding what it does in this way. It seems a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the pre DOM not getting appended?

Because `wrap` creates a **copy** of the element(s) you give it, it doesn't use the originals. From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

> A copy of this structure will be wrapped around each of the elements in the set of matched elements.

You can readily fix it by using `t.parent()` instead of `container`:

```
pre.appendTo(t.parent());
```

```js
var t = $('#t');
var container = $('<div>');
container.css('position', 'relative');
t.wrap(container);
var pre = $('<pre>');
pre.appendTo(t.parent()); // <== Change is here
```

```css
textarea {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="t" row="1" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
```

Alternately, use insert the container before the textarea and then use `append`:

```
container.insertBefore(t);
t.appendTo(container);
```

```js
var t = $('#t');
var container = $('<div>');
container.css('position', 'relative');
container.insertBefore(t); // <== Change is here
t.appendTo(container);     // <== and here
var pre = $('<pre>');
pre.appendTo(container);
```

```css
textarea {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="t" row="1" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrapped `t` using `container` though `container` ain't actually added to DOM.
use class or ID to specify where to add `pre`

```
var t = $('#t');
var container = $('<div id="foo">');
container.css('position', 'relative');
t.wrap(container);
var pre = $('<pre>');
pre.appendTo("#foo");
```

Comment: reason? and yours also. there is no  conclusive evidence that t.parent() is the div or not when you actually add pre.

Comment: Of course there is: We just wrapped a div around `t`, so `t.parent()` is the div we wrapped it with. Spewing `id`s around for no reason isn't a great idea.

Comment: what if a function is running asynchronously which might change the structure of the HTML?

Comment: No other JavaScript code can modify the dom between `t.wrap(container)` and `pre.appendTo(t.parent())`. Only the main JavaScript thread can modify the DOM, web worker threads (the only other kind of JS thread in browsers) cannot. Besides, if we're going to adduce random hypotheticals, what if something changes the `id` of your element? (It can't, because of the above, but it's just as reasonable a question.)